# Add custom new routes to rails resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I my routes file, I have defined a resource

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :invoices, only: [:index, :new]
end
```

Then I've got a route rule with corresponding path helper new_admin_invoice_path

```
new_admin_invoice GET /admin/invoices/new(.:format) admin/invoices#new
```

But how can I add two more new rules, so thуe look like

```
new_admin_incoming_invoice GET /admin/invoices/new/incoming(.:format) admin/invoices#new {:type=>:incoming}
new_admin_outgoing_invoice GET /admin/invoices/new/outgoing(.:format) admin/invoices#new {:type=>:outgoing}
```

I tried add them manually

```
resources :invoices, only: [:index, :new] do
  get 'new/incoming', on: :collection, action: :new, type: :incoming
  get 'new/outgoing', on: :collection, action: :new, type: :outgoing
end
```

But got wrong result

```
new_incoming_admin_invoices GET /admin/invoices/new/incoming(.:format) admin/invoices#new {:type=>:incoming}
new_outgoing_admin_invoices GET /admin/invoices/new/outgoing(.:format) admin/invoices#new {:type=>:outgoing}
```

How can I get exactly that routes with path helpers what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the easy rails way from official guide

```
resources :invoices, only: [:index] do
  get 'incoming', on: :new, type: :incoming, action: :new
end
```

Results to

```
incoming_new_admin_invoice GET /admin/invoices/new/incoming(.:format) admin/invoices#new {:type=>:incoming}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using a scope like this:

```
scope "/admin" do resources :invoices end
```